# Is an overloaded operator= required at this example?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

People say that if you need a destructor then you actually need an overloaded `operator=`

```
struct longlife{ };
class z
{
 z(){};
 ~z(){ for( auto it=hold.begin();it!=hold.end() ++it ) delete(*it); };
 vector<longlife*> hold;
};
```

Suppose all pointer inserted on `hold` were `new`heap allocated, why is anything else besides a deconstructor needed on this example?

By `anything else` I mean things like,

```
z& operator=( const z&ref )
{
 hold = ref.hold;
 return *this;
}
```

Would:

```
z a;
a.hold.push_back( heap_item );
z a2;
a2 = a;
```

Cause memory leak? Sometimes it's hard to understand why the rule of three is a **rule**

Comment: The first rule about the Rule of Three is that you should rather abide by the [Rule of Zero](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html).

Comment: @Xeo, I understand what the rule of three is, the question is mostly why is it a **rule**

Comment: If you ask that, then you don't understand it.

Comment: @KerrekSB Please link: http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html

Comment: @ViniyoShouta: Because otherwise the program is broken and doesn't work.

Comment: If you understand the rule, then you should see immediately why it is a rule. Without it, your code would be flat out broken. If you say `z a(b);` you immediately have an error.

Comment: @sehe: Thanks. Where's that PDF with the slides someone made about C++11 and automatic objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only is the assignment operator required, you also need to implement a copy constructor. Otherwise the compiler will provide default implementations that will result in both copies (after assignment / copy construction) containing pointers to the same `longlife` instances. Destructors of both copies will then `delete` these instances leading to undefined behavior.

```
z a;
a.hold.push_back( heap_item );
z a2;
a2 = a;
```

Both `a.hold[0]` and `a2.hold[0]` contain a pointer to the same `heap_item`; thus causing double deletion during destruction.

The easy way to avoid having to implement the assignment operator and copy constructor is to use a smart pointer to hold the `longlife` instances in the `vector`.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<longlife>> hold;
```

Now there's no need to even write a destructor for your class.

---

For C++03, your options are to use `std::tr1::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr`) instead of `unique_ptr` or use [`boost::ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) (of course, this is also an option for C++11) instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: how to use `unique_ptr` on C++03?

Comment: I'm afraid C++03 doesn't have shared_ptr too =(

Comment: @ViniyoShouta It's in the `tr1` namespace, sorry

Comment: @ViniyoShouta: `shared_ptr` was introduced with TR1. Your compiler might have it in `std::tr1::shared_ptr` if it has TR1 support. If it does not (or you prefer to) you can use the `boost::shared_ptr` from the boost libraries.

Comment: I'll look into boost libraries, unfortunatly enough vs2003 compiler doesn't have tr1 too

Answer (score 2):

Because without an assignment operator and a copy constructor you may end up with multiple `hold` vectors pointing to the same heap item, resulting in undefined behavior upon destruction:

```
z firstZ;
if (somethingIsTrue) {
    z otherZ = firstZ;
    // play with otherZ...
    // now otherZ gets destructed, along with longlife's of the firstZ
}
// now it's time to destroy the firstZ, but its longlife's are long gone!
```

Of course you would not have this problem had you used a vector of objects or a vector of "smart pointers", rather than a vector of "plain old" pointers.

See the [*Rule of Three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) for more information.

Comment: Or even better, the [Rule of Zero](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html)

Comment: @MooingDuck Icompletely agree - I even hinted at that when I mentioned smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there will be a double free here, not a memory leak.

STL containers store objects, not references. In your case `object` is a pointer. Pointers are simply copied. Your line `a2 = a;` will duplicate pointer in the vector. After that each destructor will release the pointer.

Double free is much more dangerous than the memory leak. It causes nasty undefined behavior:

```
MyStruct *p1 = new MyStruct();
delete p1;
.... do something, wait, etc.
delete p1;
```

at the same time on the other thread:

```
MyOptherStruct *p2 = new MyOtherStruct();
.... do something, wait, etc.
p2->function();
```

It may turn out that memory allocator will assign to `p2` exactly the same value that was used for `p1`, because it is free after the first call to `delete p1`. A while later second `delete p1` will also go fine because allocator thinks that this is a legitimate pointer that was given out for `p2`. The problem will appear only at `p2->function();`. Looking at the code of thread 2 it is absolutely impossible to understand what went wrong and why. This is extremely difficult to debug, especially if the system is big.

Answer (score 1):

It would cause a double delete (and crash) on the destructor of `a` or `a2` (whichever was destroyed second) because the default assignment constructor would do a binary copy of the memory state of `hold`.  So each object `a` and `a2` would end up deleting the exact same memory.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments:

> @Xeo, I understand what the rule of three is, the question is mostly
>   why is it a rule

Consider what happens here:

```
z& operator=( const z&ref )
{
 hold = ref.hold;
 return *this;
}
```

Lets say you have an instance of `z`:

```
z myz;
myz.a.hold.push_back( new long_life );
```

...and then you create a copy of this `myz`:

```
z my_other_z;
// ...
my_other_z = myz;
```

The `operator=` implementation you have provided above simply copies the contents of the `vector`.  If the `vector` has pointers, it doesn't make copies of whatever's being pointed to -- it just makes a literal copy of the pointer itself.

So after `operator=` returns, you will have 2 instances of `z` that have pointers pointing to the same thing.  When the first of those `z`s is destructed, it will delete the pointer:

```
~z(){ for( auto it=hold.begin();it!=hold.end() ++it ) delete(*it); };
```

When it comes time for the second `z` to be destroyed, it will try to `delete` the same pointer a second time.  This results in Undefined Behavior.

The solution to this problem is to make deep copies when you assign or copy objects that maintain resources that need to be allocated and deleted.  That means providing an assignment operator and a copy constructor.

That is why the rule of three is a RULE.

EDIT:

As others have mentioned, this is all better avoided altogether by using value semantics and RAII.  Reengineering your objects to use the Rule of Zero, as others have called it, is a much better approach.